# Why do YouTube Play on double tap in airpods dont works?

Tags: ipad, youtube, airpods, ipados

I connected my AirPods 2gen to IPad Air 3gen, and everything works well. The one thing that bothers me is the fact that in YouTube app pause on AirPods double-tap works, but the play doesn`t. So why is this so? Maybe I set up something wrong. Can anyone help me?
P.S. I use latest IPadOS and latest version of YoTube app.

Comment: This might have something to do with Google’s apps not running for extended periods in the background. Are you trying to play it right after pausing?

Comment: Yes, Pause and immediately  after this Play.

Comment: this might have to do with youtube implementation of apple’s gestures. Google in particular isn’t very good at keeping their apps up to date to work well on any of Apples devices. EX: Gmail still not having split-screen years after iPadOS has been introduced.

Comment: So there is no workaround ?